# WS_EX_TRANSPARENT can't click on Windows 11 taskbar

Tags: python, windows, transparent

I use `WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to set my full screen program as fully transparent, and mouse clicks can pass through to the underlying windows. Everything works fine on Windows 10, but the clicks don't work on the Windows 11 taskbar and the title bar of built-in programs(such as clock,settings,notepad,file explorer).

I created a picture to show where clicks are effective (in green) and where they are inactive (in red).
[clicks effective area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgQLY.png)

```
def set_clickthrough(self, hwnd: int) -> None:
    styles: int = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    styles: int = WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, 0x00000001)
```